# How do I create hierarchical taxonomy terms on import nodes?

Tags: entities, taxonomy-terms, feeds

I use drupal 7 and the [feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) module.

I have an excel file that contain 10 fields,So I want to import these 10 fields to specified content type as node and  for 3 fields of those create hierarchical taxonomy terms on importing file.
For example My excel file have 10 columns.

> - column 1 (cars name)
>
>   - BMW
>   - Chery
>   - MVM
> - column 2 (cars model)
>
>   - BMW 110
>   - Chery tigo 5
>   - MVM 110s
> - column 3 (color)
>
>   - red
>   - black
>   - silver
> - column 4
>
>   - ...
>   - ... . . . .

I want to import this file and after importing have 3 hierarchically taxonomy like following that assigned to nodes of content type.
Taxonomy terms is not added by me to content type yet and I want to create taxonomys and terms automatically and assign automatically to nodes.

I have created 3 taxonomy vocabulary in my drupal site (but not added any terms to those):
1- Car name (taxonomy vocabulary 1) 
2- Car model (taxonomy vocabulary 2)
3- Car color (taxonomy vocabulary 3)

I want to have taxonomy terms such as:
-car name :
  -BMV 
       - BMV 110 
           - red
  - Chery 
       - tgo5 
          - black

Please Help me for importing some fields of my file as taxonomy terms and sub terms .

I Can't type english verywell.sorry
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make 3 taxonomy feeds importers for each of the tree taxonomy vocabularies separately

[image]

Import the terms from the same source file you got - you need only to specify Term Name and matching the right columm under Mapping for "Taxonomy term processor"

In case you want to import taxonomy with the hierarchy, use [Taxonomy CSV import/export](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_csv) to put the taxonomy terms. 
Sample import file with terms&hierarchy should look like this:

BMW;BMW 5;

BMW;BMW 7;

Audi;R8;

Audi;A1;

After you run these  imports, make the final node importer. 
Change the settings to node processor. Remember under Mapping for Node processor when you map taxonomy terms to have "Search taxonomy terms by: Term name" checked on these three columns[image]

Comment: thank you @laniol. but ni this case taxonomy terms imported to site.I want to import hierarchicaly terms.

Comment: added paragraph about importing taxonmy tree.